# How to access different control that are only differentiated by a number of the end

Tags: c#, xaml

I have repetitive control name that I have to access all.

They are for example: btnTest1, btnSomething1 and btnTest2, btnSomething2.

I want to access them by "btnTest" + 1 (1 being like a index in a for loop). I don't know how to do it and I tried Control.ControlCollection.Find, but I don't have access to the method. My file is a .xaml.cs.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Button button = (Button) this.FindName("Button" + index.ToString())
```